# Lost everything while installation

Tags: data-recovery

I followed an online tutorial! All I had to do was replace Windows 8 with Ubuntu and the tutorial clearly said that you choose 'Replace OS with Ubuntu' during installation. That option was not available but the installation had one "use entire disk and install Ubuntu, this will delete your files and programs in all your operating systems"

Windows is the only Operating System and Ubuntu has wiped my whole disk now on Ubuntu, the command `mount` on terminal gives me this

```
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda           298.1G            
├─sda1 ext4   294.2G /          
├─sda2            1K            
└─sda5 swap     3.9G [SWAP]     
sr0            1024M
```

It only shows one 298 GB partition. I had very very important data on my partitions. Ebooks,Important Pictures I had collected through out the years (I am a self learned programmer). Yes, I know I Should have created a back up but I did not. My system is a laptop. How can I retrieve my Lost data from this partition?

Comment: Please quit downvoting this! I seriously am in need of help here! I switched to UBUNTU only because the so-called community was supposed to be helpful. HELP ME OUT?!

Comment: @shahabuddin - the downovotes are probably due to the heavy usage of CAPS LOCK - keep carm and we should be able to help... try the duplicate question and see if it helps. *The less you use that machine and its hard disk the more likely it is you can recover its files - use it and more data will be overwritten.*

Comment: have you tried what "Disks" is showing??
It might show your entire harddisk and all it's partitions

Comment: Please quit whining. I realize this is unpleasant for you but it's not our fault either. You chose an option that read "**Clean disk** and install ubuntu, **this will delete your files** and programs **in all your operating systems**". Well, it did exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

> "Clean disk and install ubuntu, this will delete your files and programs in all your operating systems"

You understood that this means you told the system to remove Windows? You probably need to consider that the data is gone forever.

Possible things that could save you:

1. Restore a backup. Very simple reasoning: if you have important data on a disk you make backups of that data. If your OS has a problem you re-install that OS and then restore your backup. If you do not have a backup you do not yell at other people for you wrecking your system.
2. If you did NOTHING with your system after installing Ubuntu you might get away with it with a problem called [testdisk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/testdisk/). [Here is a guide on this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=387922).
   Good luck with this. And I am serious with the "nothing": if you used Ubuntu and started installing software in sectors where Windows used to be you will corrupt the files you want to restore.

   Warning: you need to do this from a LIVE DVD. Not from your current installation.

   Focus on restoring your personal data and not on getting a complete Windows.

Comment: Thank you, and I was freaked out because it had pictures of somebody dear to me who's deceased now. Anyway, testdisk didn't really help. I removed my hard-disk from the laptop and plugged it in a desktop computer. With iCare data Recovery then I restored those files on the other computer(just the pictures to be precise). Though, a lot of important data is already lost  but I got what mattered to me the most. I'll recollect the ebooks, and tutorials that I had been recollecting all this while. Thanks though.